# Correct way of setting Python class attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

So I am trying to learn how to properly set Class attributes of a Python class, and wondering about using class functions to do so.

My beginners way has taught me to do:

```
class MyClass:
    """MyClass class instance"""
    def __init__(self, project, version, command):
        self.project = project
        self.__version = version
        self.__command = command


    """Get version used"""
    def getVersion(self):
        return self.__version

    """Get command executed"""
    def getCommand(self):
        return self.__command

    """Set version used"""
    def setVersion(self, version):
        self.__version = version
```

This is fine and simple, but this means that I already know the values of my attributes when I instantiate MyClass, since I am passing them to create my object, or if I don't pass them I would use my beginners way of `setVersion(version)` after creating MyClass object. In my search I read [this](https://www.smallsurething.com/private-methods-and-attributes-in-python/), which lead me to read about [properties](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property), and made me realize that I should not use getter/setters in Python but rather utilize properties. Is this correct?

However, I am wondering if it's Pythonic (or just even correct) to set some of the MyClass instance attributes (project, version, command) using a function. I want to do this because I want this class to do the work of finding these values from specific files by only passing 1 argument. This came to mind, but thought it might be wrong:

```
class MyClass:
    """MyClass class instance"""
    def __init__(self, project):
        self.project = project
        self._version = self.version()
        self._command = self.command()

    """Get version used"""
    def version(self):
        ...
        use `project` attribute here to get `version` from file...
        ...
        return version

    """Get command executed"""
    def command(self):
        ...
        use `project` attribute here to get `command` from file...
        ...
        return command
```

Is it even a logical way of setting instance variables by calling a class function?

Should I utilize **properties** in some ways instead?

Should I make a function outside the MyClass that finds these values returns a MyClass instance instead?

Is there a more proper Pythonic way?

I basically want to create an object with all the extra information (version, command, etc..) by just instantiating it with 1 passed attribute.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Direct attribute access is preferred to trivial getters and setters that do nothing more than wrap the access.

Comment: *I should not use getter/setters in Python but rather utilize properties. Is this correct?* Yes, there is nearly never a reason to use getter/setter instead of properties.

Comment: Complete aside, the string you're using to describe what a function does should be contained within the function rather than above a method definition. See the [PEP On doctrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)

Comment: The nice thing about properties is that if you expose an attribute directly, and people write code like `c = MyClass(); c.version = 3`, then that will continue to work (syntactically, anyway) if you change `version` to a property.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! Ok, I will start learning how to use properties properly then. Just starting to learn Python and I always feel when learning a new language that some basics change to more advance constructs, so property was a nice find.

Comment: Ah yes! @roganjosh, thank you for pointing that out. I intuitively added it as a "comment". Easily brushed it off, so glad you mentioned it.

Answer (score 7):

There are many ways to solve this, but this is how I usually do it:

```
class MyClass:
    """MyClass class instance"""
    def __init__(self, project, version, command):
        self.project = project
        self.version = version
        self.command = command

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, project):
        """ 
        Alternate constructor that takes a project 
        and extracts the other attributes from a file
        """
        #... some code to use `project` 
        #... and get `version` and `command` from file
        return cls(project, version, command)

# usage
m = MyClass.from_file('project01')
```

`classmethod` is a decorator that makes a method able to be called directly in the class, instead of the instance. 
The method then will automatically get the class as first parameter. 
`cls` is just a name that means class, like we use `self` for instances but we could use any name really. 
The main object constructor in `__init__` takes full parameters, but the the new `from_file` class method works as an alternative constructor, 
by creating an instance of the class and returning it.

Note that this is not a definite answer, but just a suggestion of a pythonic way to solve it.

Comment: What is @classmethod, does it have a special significance? Notably, is `cls` a standard convention or does it mean "class". I'm assuming this is returning the `version` and `command` values found/set in the function back to the class...then creating the instance of MyClass? Which in-turn makes my `m` object?

Comment: @bretonics your assumptions are mostly correct. I have edited the answer and added some explanantions that might address your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

1. By using keyword variables in `__init__`, you get flexibility of passing only one variable while instantiation.
2. using decorators such as, `@property` and @bar.setter enable you to access and modify the associated attributes. And I believe it is also a quite Pythonic way to do so.

The following would be my approach.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, project, version=None, command=None):
        self.project = project
        self.__version = version
        self.__command = command

    @property
    def version(self):
        return self.__version

    @version.setter
    def version(self, val):
        self.__version = val

    @property
    def command(self):
        return self.__command

    @command.setter
    def command(self, val):
        self.__command = val
```